# How can I execute python scripts from another directory

Tags: python

I am trying to follow a bad instructions website and because of that i'm getting troubles in executing scripts.

The website URL:
http://www.tripleoxygen.net/wp/2014/01/sagemcom-modem-fst-2764-gv-power-box-gvt-desbloqueio/

The following commands is the ones i'm getting trouble with:

```
./unlocker.py --mode=install
```

The steps i'm doing:

```
Open CMD
D:(my flash drive directory)
python
unlocker.py --mode=install
```

What I get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

but I don't think i'm executing the script, because there is no stdin in the file...
So what I'm asking is:

Are my steps wrong?

How can I execute the script correctly from another directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That website doesn't say to start python then enter `unlocker.py`. It says to type `./unlocker.py` from the command prompt, not the Python prompt. You may need to do `python unlocker.py`, but again, you're doing that from the command prompt.

Comment: DUDE, you managed to get the script working, well now I have another problem, by looking into the py code, I figure I have to execute this script in my modem, how may I send commands over to my modem to execute this script? '-' (I think you are Brazilian so you can understand the website more easily also)

Comment: I was thinking of using PUTTY to connect with the modem and then send the commands to it, but there are two problems with it: How can I send commands where the flash drive is mounted? and doesn't my modem need to have python installed in order to run scripts?